# Multiple function in onClick event

Tags: reactjs, button, onclick, toast

I have a button with an `onclick event`.  This button closes a dialog and changes its value.
I have two functions, one that changes the buttons value `handleChange` and the  other that closes the dialog  and displays an alert to confirm `onSubmit`.

---

**Problem**:

I tried calling the two functions separetly on the `onClick event`. While doing this the function `handleChange` works and the  `onSubmit` does not.

```
onClick={() => {
             handleChange();
            onSubmit();
          }}
```

So I tried  calling the  `handleChange`  function inside the  `onSubmit` function.

```
 const onSubmit = ()=> {
    reset();
    toast("Default Notification !");
   
    handleChange();
   };




onClick={() => {
            
            onSubmit();
          }}
```

**Where I think it's the problem**:

My `onSubmit` function has an alert made of this library https://fkhadra.github.io/react-toastify/introduction/ and **can not be changed** for another library or a simple `alert();`

BUT if I try with an `alert();`  the two functions are displayed but **I want the  `handleChange();` to run first and then the other**.

For this I tried calling my `onSubmit` function inside `handleChange();`  but it does not work. Also tried changing the order of calling the functions in the `onclick` event but it doesn't work either

**Edit**

My on submit function :

```
const onSubmit = ()=> {
    reset();
    alert("Default Notification !");
   
    handleChange();
   };
```

My handleChange function:

```
 const handleChange = () => {
    setChange((prevState) => (prevState === 2 ? 0 : prevState + 1));
  };
```

My onclick event:

```
<Button
      variant="contained"
      onClick={() => {
        // handleChange();
        onSubmit();
      }}
    >
```

Comment: I think we will need more infos here. Share the code of both the functions perhaps

Comment: @Dominik I've updated the question, please review it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the function or statement you want to execute after `handleChange()` inside `setTimeout` with 0 milliseconds. This will make sure the function or statement gets executed after all the synchronous tasks are finished executing (in this case `handleChange()`).

```
const onSubmit = () => {
  handleChange();
  setTimeout(() => {
    alert("Default notification");   // or any other function or statement you want to execute after handleChange().
  }, 0);
};
```

Comment: I didn't work out for me. When I use toast as the statement , the alert doesn't show and when I use alert it shows it first.. check my code sample https://codesandbox.io/s/chip-1z4g1?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @Karol Have you tried in a code editor instead of sandbox? Because it works fine for me in a code editor. Yeah, without `setTimeout`, `alert()` will execute before `handleChange()`.

Comment: @Karol Also, if you are making use of `toast`, then you have to make use of `<ToastContainer />` and import the necessary files. Otherwise, it won't show anything.